# Shell script to launch Java app won't execute

Tags: java, shell

I am using debian and xterm.

I have created a file 'run.sh' containing the following:

```
java -cp bin Main
read -n1 -r ip "Press any key to continue..." key
```

In Properties window I gave it permission to run as program.

Double clicking the file does nothing. Right click 'Execute' does nothing. Open-with UXTerm does nothing.

If I open a terminal in the same directory and type

```
java -cp bin Main
```

then it will run, but the shell script file never works.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: try launching same script from terminal and see the error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your shell script file doesn't seem to have a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) line,

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
java -cp bin Main
read -n1 -r ip "Press any key to continue..." key
```

and make sure it has a execute permissions

```
chmod a+x <script_file>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a shebang line at the top of your file: `#!/usr/bin/bash`. This tells the operating system that the file is in fact a bash executable rather than a normal file. Alternatively, execute the script by entering `bash run.sh` from the command line.